# Iterate over a Map containing List in linear time

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

I would like to iterate over a `Map<Object,List<Object>>` and extract such `Map.Entry` in which any of the objects in `List<Object>` (the values), meet a certain condition.  
I can see two ways to do this:

> 1) The obvious way would be to extract the entry-set and loop over the list (the value). 
>    2) Convert this Map to Guava's MultiMap, loop over the values and if the condition is met, flag the key and extract the actual List from the map.

I would like to avoid the first method as it is a non-linear solution. Are there any other, more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: What about the first approach isn't linear time?  It's linear in the total number of objects.  These two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: I don't really understand why 1) should not be linear time. Also, do you have a performance problem as identified by profiling, or is it just a guess?

Comment: In the first approach, I will first have to iterate over all the entry sets.  In each iteration, I will need to again loop for its values to check the condition.  That makes it a nested-for loop.  Wouldn't that make this non-linear?

Comment: I think the op wants to avoid looping inside a loop. Given the layout of the data it would be hard if not impossible

Comment: @Axel - Yes, this is a performance issue.

Comment: >> Wouldn't that make this non-linear? - No, it wouldn't. It will be O(number of values). The same as for Guava MultiMap.

Comment: You will absolutely have to iterate all the values of all the map entries.  There's no way around it.  Any solution will do that.  Accept it and move on.

Comment: @Nolequen   Hold on, so the Guava's multimap does the same thing? I guess, there is no more efficient way to do this.  I wonder how much streaming can help with this.

Comment: Streaming is syntactic sugar that hides for loops. It will still be iterating through all of the values. If you have to check to see if every value meets a condition, then by definition you... have to check every value. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Streaming can't change the layout of the data. And it starts to break even around 10k items. It may look one loop less but it is performed behind the scenes. You need to look into parallel/threading solution

Comment: I was thinking of Java 8 parallel streams, but yes,  the only way to do this more efficiently would be reading the map in parallel threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to go through all of the values if you have to check each of them. To go through all of the values you'd have to do something like:

```
public List<Object> getEntriesThatMeetCondition(Map<Object, List<Object>> input) {
    List<Map.Entry> output = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator it = input.entrySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();

        List inputList = (List<Object>) entry.getValue();

        for(Object object : inputList) {
            if(meetsCondition(object)) {
                output.add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's linear in the sense that you're going through each item once.